# Compare empty field to string?

Tags: android, string, compare

I use my cursor to get a certain value out of my database table. It gets it out of a column with the type 'TEXT'. The idea is that the standard value of the column is blank, but when a certain button is clicked, a query will add "true" to it.

```
String var = c.getString(1); //use cursor to get value
```

But when I want to use this to compare to a string, f.e.

```
if(var.equals("true")) {
//do something crazy
}
```

I get an error on items where there is nothing filled in the DB. Only the fields where actually "true" is filled in won't give an error. I tried c.getString(1).toString(); but this doesn't do the trick... any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get? Does `c.getString()` return `null` if there is _nothing filled in the DB_ ?

Comment: NullpointerException.. I will try the method of AmitD below and see if that will do the trick

Comment: In addition to the check for `null`, its a good practice to have a default value inserted into the database for each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check should be like below

```
if("true".equals(var)) {
```

So that you will not get `NullPointerException`

As suggested in [Cursor#getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) Javadoc

> The result and **whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null** or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

You should use [Cursor#isNull](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull%28int%29) or [Cursor#moveToFirst](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) before checking value from database.

```
 if(!c.isNull(1))
 //Get Value here

Or 

if(c.moveToFirst())
 //get value here
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like:

```
if(var != null && !var.equals(""))
```

this way you are controlling both null and empty strings..

Answer (score 1):

```
if("true".equals(var)) {
  //do something crazy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the casting (you should read the LogCat). You should first check that the cursor contains data before fetching it:

```
String var = "";    
if (c.moveToFirst())
var = c.getString(1);
```

then do your check.

```
if(var.equals("true")) { //do something crazy }
```

Comment: There is data in it, the thing is that only some fields are empty, but not all of them. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, you are not initiating var if cursor is empty (so I assume the logCat is pointing to the line where if statment). Giving it an initial value ("") will not cause nullPointerException if the cursor is empty

Comment: Ok i see your modified answer now. Problem is that it is not the only field, so it will pass on the if statement above, and still return a null result to the var, no? Or will it remain an empty string if it gets a null back from the getString?

Comment: if var is null, the if statment will give NullPointerException

Comment: You define var with c.getString, so if the DB is empty (or cursor is empty), var will be null. So, you give it an initial value "" and then change this value with c.getString if c.moveToFirst returns true (i.e. cursor is not empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
 firstly check the 
 if(var.trim.equals("")) {
    //do your task
 }
```